# Does DataNucleus have batch (bulk) fetch feature for M-1 and 1-1 associations?

Tags: java, jpa, datanucleus

Is there any analog feature in DataNucleus like Hibernate @BatchSize or EclipseLink @BatchFetch(BatchFetchType.IN) ?
Fetch groups and join fetch in JPQL is IMO leak of abstraction - caller is should to now what data it needed for further processing. In complex domain code is close to impossible to know what is needed for concrete business call. Blindly fetch ALL potentially needed data is far from efficient way and can trigger OOM.
Tons of fetch queries by single ID with JOIN on FK is effectively kill my app performance. Not in view layer but business logic layer.
Any suggestions are welcome!

Main entity:

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "create_seq_question", sequenceName = "seq_question", allocationSize = 1)
public class Question {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "create_seq_question")
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@NotNull
private Date dateOfPost;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
private Status status = Status.NEW;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private ChatMessage chatMessage;

//other fields and methods
}
```

Related entity:

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "create_seq_chatmessage", sequenceName = "seq_chatmessage", allocationSize = 1)
public class ChatMessage {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChatMessage.class);

public enum Type {
    QUESTION /*0*/, ANSWER /*1*/, TECHNICAL /*2*/, SUPERVISOR /*3*/, CLARIFYING_QUESTION /*4*/, TASK /*5*/, COMMUNICATION /*6*/, MARKETING /*7*/;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "create_seq_chatmessage")
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@NotNull
private String message;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date deleteDate;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date inputDate;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
private Type type;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "chatMessage", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Question question;

//other fields and methods

}
```

JPQL Query:

```
    List<Question> questions = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT q FROM Question q", Question.class).getResultList();
    for (Question question : questions) {
        ChatMessage cm = question.getChatMessage();
        //some logic
    }
```

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT 'core.domain.Question' AS DN_TYPE,Q.QUID,Q.ASTROLOGERSELECTIONTYPE,Q.CANCELLINGREASON,Q.CANCELLINGREASONTEXT,Q.CREATED,Q.DATEOFPOST,Q.ID,Q.PRIORITY,Q.STATUS,Q."TYPE",Q.UPDATED,Q.VERSION FROM QUESTION Q
SELECT B0.DATEOFSHARE,B0.DELETEDATE,B0.HIDEINWEBCHATHISTORY,B0.ID,B0.INPUTDATE,B0.ISRATETYPEBUTTON,B0.ISSHAREREQUIRED,B0.ISSHARED,B0.RATEDATE,B0.ISMARKNEEDED,B0.MARKVALUE,B0.MESSAGE,B0.MINIMUMMARKSCOREFORRATE,B0.RATEBUTTONTEXT,B0.ISRATED,B0.READDATE,B0.SHARINGTYPE,B0.STORETYPE,B0."TYPE",B0.UPDATED,B0.VERSION FROM QUESTION A0 LEFT OUTER JOIN CHATMESSAGE B0 ON A0.CHATMESSAGE_ID = B0.ID WHERE A0.ID = <101>
SELECT B0.DATEOFSHARE,B0.DELETEDATE,B0.HIDEINWEBCHATHISTORY,B0.ID,B0.INPUTDATE,B0.ISRATETYPEBUTTON,B0.ISSHAREREQUIRED,B0.ISSHARED,B0.RATEDATE,B0.ISMARKNEEDED,B0.MARKVALUE,B0.MESSAGE,B0.MINIMUMMARKSCOREFORRATE,B0.RATEBUTTONTEXT,B0.ISRATED,B0.READDATE,B0.SHARINGTYPE,B0.STORETYPE,B0."TYPE",B0.UPDATED,B0.VERSION FROM QUESTION A0 LEFT OUTER JOIN CHATMESSAGE B0 ON A0.CHATMESSAGE_ID = B0.ID WHERE A0.ID = <102>
SELECT B0.DATEOFSHARE,B0.DELETEDATE,B0.HIDEINWEBCHATHISTORY,B0.ID,B0.INPUTDATE,B0.ISRATETYPEBUTTON,B0.ISSHAREREQUIRED,B0.ISSHARED,B0.RATEDATE,B0.ISMARKNEEDED,B0.MARKVALUE,B0.MESSAGE,B0.MINIMUMMARKSCOREFORRATE,B0.RATEBUTTONTEXT,B0.ISRATED,B0.READDATE,B0.SHARINGTYPE,B0.STORETYPE,B0."TYPE",B0.UPDATED,B0.VERSION FROM QUESTION A0 LEFT OUTER JOIN CHATMESSAGE B0 ON A0.CHATMESSAGE_ID = B0.ID WHERE A0.ID = <103>
SELECT B0.DATEOFSHARE,B0.DELETEDATE,B0.HIDEINWEBCHATHISTORY,B0.ID,B0.INPUTDATE,B0.ISRATETYPEBUTTON,B0.ISSHAREREQUIRED,B0.ISSHARED,B0.RATEDATE,B0.ISMARKNEEDED,B0.MARKVALUE,B0.MESSAGE,B0.MINIMUMMARKSCOREFORRATE,B0.RATEBUTTONTEXT,B0.ISRATED,B0.READDATE,B0.SHARINGTYPE,B0.STORETYPE,B0."TYPE",B0.UPDATED,B0.VERSION FROM QUESTION A0 LEFT OUTER JOIN CHATMESSAGE B0 ON A0.CHATMESSAGE_ID = B0.ID WHERE A0.ID = <104>
SELECT B0.DATEOFSHARE,B0.DELETEDATE,B0.HIDEINWEBCHATHISTORY,B0.ID,B0.INPUTDATE,B0.ISRATETYPEBUTTON,B0.ISSHAREREQUIRED,B0.ISSHARED,B0.RATEDATE,B0.ISMARKNEEDED,B0.MARKVALUE,B0.MESSAGE,B0.MINIMUMMARKSCOREFORRATE,B0.RATEBUTTONTEXT,B0.ISRATED,B0.READDATE,B0.SHARINGTYPE,B0.STORETYPE,B0."TYPE",B0.UPDATED,B0.VERSION FROM QUESTION A0 LEFT OUTER JOIN CHATMESSAGE B0 ON A0.CHATMESSAGE_ID = B0.ID WHERE A0.ID = <105>
SELECT B0.DATEOFSHARE,B0.DELETEDATE,B0.HIDEINWEBCHATHISTORY,B0.ID,B0.INPUTDATE,B0.ISRATETYPEBUTTON,B0.ISSHAREREQUIRED,B0.ISSHARED,B0.RATEDATE,B0.ISMARKNEEDED,B0.MARKVALUE,B0.MESSAGE,B0.MINIMUMMARKSCOREFORRATE,B0.RATEBUTTONTEXT,B0.ISRATED,B0.READDATE,B0.SHARINGTYPE,B0.STORETYPE,B0."TYPE",B0.UPDATED,B0.VERSION FROM QUESTION A0 LEFT OUTER JOIN CHATMESSAGE B0 ON A0.CHATMESSAGE_ID = B0.ID WHERE A0.ID = <106>
```

That classic 1+N lazy loading problem + fetch queries not just fetch by PK, but LEFT OUTER JOIN with main entity table. Other providers fetch FK in first query and perform lazy loading just by PK of related entity.
I know about "fetch-fk-only" extension, but it result is even worse:

```
 SELECT 'core.domain.Question' AS DN_TYPE,Q.QUID,Q.ASTROLOGERSELECTIONTYPE,Q.CANCELLINGREASON,Q.CANCELLINGREASONTEXT,Q.CREATED,Q.DATEOFPOST,Q.ID,Q.PRIORITY,Q.STATUS,Q."TYPE",Q.UPDATED,Q.VERSION FROM QUESTION Q
 SELECT A0.CHATMESSAGE_ID FROM QUESTION A0 WHERE A0.ID = <101>
 SELECT A0.DATEOFSHARE,A0.DELETEDATE,A0.HIDEINWEBCHATHISTORY,A0.INPUTDATE,A0.ISRATETYPEBUTTON,A0.ISSHAREREQUIRED,A0.ISSHARED,A0.RATEDATE,A0.ISMARKNEEDED,A0.MARKVALUE,A0.MESSAGE,A0.MINIMUMMARKSCOREFORRATE,A0.RATEBUTTONTEXT,A0.ISRATED,A0.READDATE,A0.SHARINGTYPE,A0.STORETYPE,A0."TYPE",A0.UPDATED,A0.VERSION FROM CHATMESSAGE A0 WHERE A0.ID = <101>
 SELECT A0.CHATMESSAGE_ID FROM QUESTION A0 WHERE A0.ID = <102>
 SELECT A0.DATEOFSHARE,A0.DELETEDATE,A0.HIDEINWEBCHATHISTORY,A0.INPUTDATE,A0.ISRATETYPEBUTTON,A0.ISSHAREREQUIRED,A0.ISSHARED,A0.RATEDATE,A0.ISMARKNEEDED,A0.MARKVALUE,A0.MESSAGE,A0.MINIMUMMARKSCOREFORRATE,A0.RATEBUTTONTEXT,A0.ISRATED,A0.READDATE,A0.SHARINGTYPE,A0.STORETYPE,A0."TYPE",A0.UPDATED,A0.VERSION FROM CHATMESSAGE A0 WHERE A0.ID = <102>
 SELECT A0.CHATMESSAGE_ID FROM QUESTION A0 WHERE A0.ID = <103>
 SELECT A0.DATEOFSHARE,A0.DELETEDATE,A0.HIDEINWEBCHATHISTORY,A0.INPUTDATE,A0.ISRATETYPEBUTTON,A0.ISSHAREREQUIRED,A0.ISSHARED,A0.RATEDATE,A0.ISMARKNEEDED,A0.MARKVALUE,A0.MESSAGE,A0.MINIMUMMARKSCOREFORRATE,A0.RATEBUTTONTEXT,A0.ISRATED,A0.READDATE,A0.SHARINGTYPE,A0.STORETYPE,A0."TYPE",A0.UPDATED,A0.VERSION FROM CHATMESSAGE A0 WHERE A0.ID = <103>
 SELECT A0.CHATMESSAGE_ID FROM QUESTION A0 WHERE A0.ID = <104>
 SELECT A0.DATEOFSHARE,A0.DELETEDATE,A0.HIDEINWEBCHATHISTORY,A0.INPUTDATE,A0.ISRATETYPEBUTTON,A0.ISSHAREREQUIRED,A0.ISSHARED,A0.RATEDATE,A0.ISMARKNEEDED,A0.MARKVALUE,A0.MESSAGE,A0.MINIMUMMARKSCOREFORRATE,A0.RATEBUTTONTEXT,A0.ISRATED,A0.READDATE,A0.SHARINGTYPE,A0.STORETYPE,A0."TYPE",A0.UPDATED,A0.VERSION FROM CHATMESSAGE A0 WHERE A0.ID = <104>
```

N*2+1 (!) queries. 
If I make relation not lazy I've get this:

```
 SELECT 'core.domain.Question' AS DN_TYPE,Q.QUID,Q.ASTROLOGERSELECTIONTYPE,Q.CANCELLINGREASON,Q.CANCELLINGREASONTEXT,Q.CHATMESSAGE_ID,Q.CREATED,Q.DATEOFPOST,Q.ID,Q.PRIORITY,Q.STATUS,Q."TYPE",Q.UPDATED,Q.VERSION FROM QUESTION Q
 SELECT A0.DATEOFSHARE,A0.DELETEDATE,A0.HIDEINWEBCHATHISTORY,A0.INPUTDATE,A0.ISRATETYPEBUTTON,A0.ISSHAREREQUIRED,A0.ISSHARED,A0.RATEDATE,A0.ISMARKNEEDED,A0.MARKVALUE,A0.MESSAGE,A0.MINIMUMMARKSCOREFORRATE,A0.RATEBUTTONTEXT,A0.ISRATED,A0.READDATE,A0.SHARINGTYPE,A0.STORETYPE,A0."TYPE",A0.UPDATED,A0.VERSION FROM CHATMESSAGE A0 WHERE A0.ID = <101>
 SELECT A0.DATEOFSHARE,A0.DELETEDATE,A0.HIDEINWEBCHATHISTORY,A0.INPUTDATE,A0.ISRATETYPEBUTTON,A0.ISSHAREREQUIRED,A0.ISSHARED,A0.RATEDATE,A0.ISMARKNEEDED,A0.MARKVALUE,A0.MESSAGE,A0.MINIMUMMARKSCOREFORRATE,A0.RATEBUTTONTEXT,A0.ISRATED,A0.READDATE,A0.SHARINGTYPE,A0.STORETYPE,A0."TYPE",A0.UPDATED,A0.VERSION FROM CHATMESSAGE A0 WHERE A0.ID = <102>
 SELECT A0.DATEOFSHARE,A0.DELETEDATE,A0.HIDEINWEBCHATHISTORY,A0.INPUTDATE,A0.ISRATETYPEBUTTON,A0.ISSHAREREQUIRED,A0.ISSHARED,A0.RATEDATE,A0.ISMARKNEEDED,A0.MARKVALUE,A0.MESSAGE,A0.MINIMUMMARKSCOREFORRATE,A0.RATEBUTTONTEXT,A0.ISRATED,A0.READDATE,A0.SHARINGTYPE,A0.STORETYPE,A0."TYPE",A0.UPDATED,A0.VERSION FROM CHATMESSAGE A0 WHERE A0.ID = <103>
 SELECT A0.DATEOFSHARE,A0.DELETEDATE,A0.HIDEINWEBCHATHISTORY,A0.INPUTDATE,A0.ISRATETYPEBUTTON,A0.ISSHAREREQUIRED,A0.ISSHARED,A0.RATEDATE,A0.ISMARKNEEDED,A0.MARKVALUE,A0.MESSAGE,A0.MINIMUMMARKSCOREFORRATE,A0.RATEBUTTONTEXT,A0.ISRATED,A0.READDATE,A0.SHARINGTYPE,A0.STORETYPE,A0."TYPE",A0.UPDATED,A0.VERSION FROM CHATMESSAGE A0 WHERE A0.ID = <104>
 SELECT A0.DATEOFSHARE,A0.DELETEDATE,A0.HIDEINWEBCHATHISTORY,A0.INPUTDATE,A0.ISRATETYPEBUTTON,A0.ISSHAREREQUIRED,A0.ISSHARED,A0.RATEDATE,A0.ISMARKNEEDED,A0.MARKVALUE,A0.MESSAGE,A0.MINIMUMMARKSCOREFORRATE,A0.RATEBUTTONTEXT,A0.ISRATED,A0.READDATE,A0.SHARINGTYPE,A0.STORETYPE,A0."TYPE",A0.UPDATED,A0.VERSION FROM CHATMESSAGE A0 WHERE A0.ID = <105>
 SELECT A0.DATEOFSHARE,A0.DELETEDATE,A0.HIDEINWEBCHATHISTORY,A0.INPUTDATE,A0.ISRATETYPEBUTTON,A0.ISSHAREREQUIRED,A0.ISSHARED,A0.RATEDATE,A0.ISMARKNEEDED,A0.MARKVALUE,A0.MESSAGE,A0.MINIMUMMARKSCOREFORRATE,A0.RATEBUTTONTEXT,A0.ISRATED,A0.READDATE,A0.SHARINGTYPE,A0.STORETYPE,A0."TYPE",A0.UPDATED,A0.VERSION FROM CHATMESSAGE A0 WHERE A0.ID = <106>
 SELECT A0.DATEOFSHARE,A0.DELETEDATE,A0.HIDEINWEBCHATHISTORY,A0.INPUTDATE,A0.ISRATETYPEBUTTON,A0.ISSHAREREQUIRED,A0.ISSHARED,A0.RATEDATE,A0.ISMARKNEEDED,A0.MARKVALUE,A0.MESSAGE,A0.MINIMUMMARKSCOREFORRATE,A0.RATEBUTTONTEXT,A0.ISRATED,A0.READDATE,A0.SHARINGTYPE,A0.STORETYPE,A0."TYPE",A0.UPDATED,A0.VERSION FROM CHATMESSAGE A0 WHERE A0.ID = <107>
```

Just after getResultList() before any touch of relation. That is the worst variant because N+1 queries without actually touch lazy relation.

What I need is:

```
SELECT 'core.domain.Question' AS DN_TYPE,Q.QUID,Q.ASTROLOGERSELECTIONTYPE,Q.CANCELLINGREASON,Q.CANCELLINGREASONTEXT,Q.CHATMESSAGE_ID,Q.CREATED,Q.DATEOFPOST,Q.ID,Q.PRIORITY,Q.STATUS,Q."TYPE",Q.UPDATED,Q.VERSION FROM QUESTION Q
```

After getResultList(). And then when I've touch relation:

```
SELECT A0.DATEOFSHARE,A0.DELETEDATE,A0.HIDEINWEBCHATHISTORY,A0.INPUTDATE,A0.ISRATETYPEBUTTON,A0.ISSHAREREQUIRED,A0.ISSHARED,A0.RATEDATE,A0.ISMARKNEEDED,A0.MARKVALUE,A0.MESSAGE,A0.MINIMUMMARKSCOREFORRATE,A0.RATEBUTTONTEXT,A0.ISRATED,A0.READDATE,A0.SHARINGTYPE,A0.STORETYPE,A0."TYPE",A0.UPDATED,A0.VERSION FROM CHATMESSAGE A0 WHERE A0.ID IN (<101>, <102>, <103>, <104>, <105>)
```

Comment: When the query candidate related field is 1-N I think DataNucleus does a "bulk Fetch" (see its log) and you get statements like you say you want with the IN clause (which makes sense since you can't include a 1-N in the original query) ... so get 1+1 queries. For 1-1/N-1 I simply include the field in the original query, and it fetches fine for my cases (so I get 1 query). If you get something other I'd suggest you talk to your JPA provider via their support forum.

Comment: Hibernate, EclipseLink have batch fetch of *-1 association.
OpenJPA - not (OPENJPA-2296). DataNucleus as now show the worst results among all providers because it not fetch FK in first query and use JOIN for lazy fetch queries (access to 2 relations instead of 1 on RDBMS side). EAGER fetch IMO is not option for truly transparent persistence.
May be anyone know how to tune DataNucleus because it have other  strong features that I want to use.

Comment: As I said, if you have a problem why not approach your JPA provider and ask them if you have misconfigured things rather than ranting on some other site. I use it without problems for *-1, fetching the FK. I don't think their devs come on here. Maybe you can contribute something to it if you are a significant user of it, since that is what is a better way in the open source world.

Comment: I've post it here because it is option 5 of DataNucleus support guide (http://www.datanucleus.org/support.html) and StackOverflow have by far more wide auditory then DataNucleus Forum (option 4).

Comment: @NeilStockton Thanx for pointing to bulk fetch, you right it is only for 1-N associations. I've investigating code for analog for *-1.